# Next/Previous Button in html with labels

Tags: html, button, label

I added a previous and next button to my site on blogger, however I find it difficult to add conditions so that only post with the same labels appear upon clicking on the buttons. Below is my code.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
             
    <div class='nav-buttons-container'>
               
   <b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
      <a class='previous-button' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl'>
        <div class='icon'>
          <svg class='h-6 w-6' fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
            <path d='M11 19l-7-7 7-7m8 14l-7-7 7-7' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
          </svg>
        </div>

        <div class='label'>Previous</div>
      </a>
  </b:if>
               
       <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>

      <a class='next-button' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl'>
        <div class='label'>Next</div>
        <div class='icon'>
          <svg class='h-6 w-6' fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
            <path d='M13 5l7 7-7 7M5 5l7 7-7 7' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>
   </b:if>          
    </div>
 </b:if>
```

In this modified code, I tired first store the label of the current post in the currentLabel variable using b:with. Then for the previous and next buttons I use b:loop to iterate through all the posts. While inside the loop, I check if the label of the current post matches the currentLabel. However it does not work, can any one solve my doubts?

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
  <b:with value='data:post.labels[0]' var='currentLabel' />

  <b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
    <b:loop index='i' values='data:posts' var='post'>
      <b:if cond='data:i > 0'>
        <b:with value='data:posts[i-1].labels[0]' var='prevLabel'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.labels and data:post.labels[0] == data:currentLabel and data:prevLabel == data:currentLabel'>
            <a class='previous-button' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl'>
              <div class='icon'>
                <svg class='h-6 w-6' fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
                  <path d='M11 19l-7-7 7-7m8 14l-7-7 7-7' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div class='label'>Previous</div>
            </a>
          </b:if>
        </b:with>
      </b:if>
    </b:loop>
  </b:if>
  <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
    <b:loop index='i' values='data:posts' var='post'>
      <b:if cond='data:i < data:posts.length - 1'>
        <b:with value='data:posts[i+1].labels[0]' var='nextLabel'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.labels and data:post.labels[0] == data:currentLabel and data:nextLabel == data:currentLabel'>
            <a class='next-button' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl'>
              <div class='label'>Next</div>
              <div class='icon'>
                <svg class='h-6 w-6' fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
                  <path d='M13 5l7 7-7 7M5 5l7 7-7 7' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
                </svg>
              </div>
            </a>
          </b:if>
        </b:with>
      </b:if>
    </b:loop>
  </b:if>
</b:if>
```